PowerApp (Microsoft Dynamics CRM) view for with a column for many-to-many relationship
I have an entity "contact" with a many-to-many relationship with the entity "email preference". The "contact" also has a one-to-many relationship with the "account" entity. I want to create a view for contacts that shows what "email preference" each contact has, so I can use it on the "account page" to make a table like this:
| contact          | preference     |
| --------         | -------------- |
| joe@email.com    | Invoices       |
| joe@email.com    | Orders         |
| jane2@email.com  | Orders         |

Is this possible? When I try to add the "preference" column to a "contact" view I don't have anything available under related to add for preferences. It shows up if it is a one-many relationship, but I need the many-to-many relationship.

If "contact" has a one-to-many relationship with "account", then under "account" entity, it would not show different contact right? joe@email.com and jane2@email.com should not display under the same account.
